# Smarter way to calculate adjacent mines in Minesweeper using Java 8 Streams

Tags: java, java-stream

Hey guys I started programming a year ago and recently discovered streams. So I decided to complete my old tasks using streams whenever I could just to get used to them. I know it might not be smart to force using them but it's just practice.

One of my old tasks was to program Minesweeper and right now I try to find a better solution for counting adjacent mines whenever I click a field.

Some details:
I saved a bunch of mines in a Mine[] (arsenal.getArsenal()) and each of the mines has an x and y value. Whenever I click on a field I need to count all mines around the clicked field (from x-1,y-1 till x+1,y+1).

My current solutions are:

```
    private int calculateNearby(int x, int y) {
        return (int) Arrays.stream(arsenal.getArsenal())
                           .filter(mine -> mine.getX() == x + 1 && mine.getY() == y
                                   || mine.getX() == x && mine.getY() == y + 1
                                   || mine.getX() == x - 1 && mine.getY() == y
                                   || mine.getX() == x && mine.getY() == y - 1
                                   || mine.getX() == x - 1 && mine.getY() == y - 1
                                   || mine.getX() == x - 1 && mine.getY() == y + 1
                                   || mine.getX() == x + 1 && mine.getY() == y - 1
                                   || mine.getX() == x + 1 && mine.getY() == y + 1)
                           .count();
    }
    
    private int calculateNearby(int x, int y) {
        return (int) Arrays.stream(arsenal.getArsenal())
                           .filter(mine ->
                               {
                                   boolean b = false;
                                   for (int i = -1; i < 2; ++i) {
                                       for (int j = -1; j < 2; ++j) {
                                           if ((x != 0 || y != 0) && mine.getX() == x + i && mine.getY() == y + j) {
                                               b = true;
                                           }
                                       }
                                   }
                                   return b;
                               })
                           .count();
    }
```

Both solutions work fine but the first looks "wrong" because of all the cases and the seconds uses for-loops which I basically tried to avoid using.

It would be nice if you could show me a better (ideally shorter) solution using streams. :D

I'm sorry if there's already a thread about this. I really tried to find anything related but there either isn't anything or I searched for the wrong keywords.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify your stream condition. Instead of checking each case if getX() equals x, x-1 or x+1 you can just check if getX() is greater or equals than x-1 and smaller or equals x+1. The same for getY().

```
return (int) Arrays.stream(arsenal.getArsenal())
        .filter(mine -> mine.getX() >= x - 1 && mine.getX() <= x + 1 
                && mine.getY() >= y - 1 && mine.getY() <= y + 1)
        .count();
```

You could also create a method for the check to make the code more readable.

```
private int calculateNearby(int x, int y) {
    return (int) Arrays.stream(arsenal.getArsenal())
            .filter(mine -> inRange(mine.getX(), x)
                    && inRange(mine.getY(), y))
            .count();
}

private boolean inRange(int actual, int target) {
    return actual >= target - 1 && actual <= target + 1;
}
```

Comment: You can also outsource the filtering condition into a method, so it becomes more readable and understandable.

Comment: That's a great idea as well! Thank you :)

Comment: You are counting the mine at `x,y` as well (`mine.getX() == x, mine.getY() == y`).

Comment: @Milgo I just saw that my first comment is gone. It either got deleted or I messed up posting it. Thanks a lot for your Solution! :) You were so fast as well. :)

Comment: @Polygnome Counting the field (x,y) doesn't matter. Because if it's a mine I already lost. That's something I didn't include in this snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to check if the absolute distance in each direction is less than or equal to 1:

```
private int calculateNearby(int x, int y) {
    return (int) Arrays.stream(arsenal.getArsenal())
        .filter(mine -> Math.abs(mine.getX() - x) <= 1 && Math.abs(mine.getY() - y) <= 1)
        .count();
}
```

Note that this also counts a mine which is at the point (x, y) which is not the case with the code in the question.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it counts the point (x,y). Because if the point (x,y) is a mine I already lost. That's a precondition I didn't include in this snippet. 

So it works exactly like I would like it to. 
Thanks mate :)

Answer (score 0):

When is a mine adjacent? When its only one field horizontally or vertically away.

Horizontal distance is `Math.abs(mine.getX() - x)`, vertical distance is `Math.abs(mine.getY() - y)`. It doesn't matter if its `-1` or `1`, just that it is one field away.

But it shouldn't be more than one field, either vertical or horizontal be away, so `max(dx, dy) == 1`.

```java
Predicate<Mine> isAdjacent = mine -> 
    Math.max(
        Math.abs(mine.getX() - x)
        Math.abs(mine.getY() - y)
    ) == 1;

return (int) Arrays.stream(arsenal.getArsenal())
        .filter(isAdjacent) 
        .count();
```